# When mail is triggered getting blank fields in mail

Tags: c#

Below is the code for sending mail.Iam not getting any error or exception but when mail is triggered iam getting blank fields for region name,location name and partner code. Partner name also is displayed.

```
          if (objUser.UserMasterId == 0)
          {

             objUser.FunctionalityId = 10; //Partner Creation

             dtPartnerMailDetails = UserMasterBL.GetPartnerMailDetails(objUser);

             if (dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
             {

                 objUser.RegionName = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["RegionName"].ToString();
                 objUser.LocationName = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["LocationName"].ToString();
                 objUser.PartnerCode = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["PartnerCode"].ToString();
                 objUser.PartnerName = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["partnername"].ToString();
             }
                dtMailDetails = UserMasterBL.GetMailDetails(objUser);

                    if (dtMailDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                       string strMailFROM = "WiproIMSCertificationPortal@wipro.com";
                        string ToMailIds = dtMailDetails.Rows[0]["ToMailIds"].ToString();
                        string CCMailIds = dtMailDetails.Rows[0]["CCMailIds"].ToString();

                       /* string Region = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["regionname"].ToString();
                        string Location = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["locationname"].ToString();
                        string PartnerCode = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["PartnerCode"].ToString();
                        string partnername = dtPartnerMailDetails.Rows[0]["partnername"].ToString();*/

                        string Region = objUser.RegionName;
                        string Location = objUser.LocationName;
                        string PartnerCode = objUser.PartnerCode;
                        string PartnerName = objUser.PartnerName;
                        //string partnercodeauto = objUser.PartnerCodeid;

                        string strmailBody = "<html><body><font face='Verdana' size=2 color=#0E6192>";

                        strmailBody += "Dear Administrator " + "<br/><br/>";
                        strmailBody += "Kindly approve  below request, Created by " + objUser.PartnerName + "<br/> <br/>";
                        strmailBody += "<br/><br/>";

                        strmailBody += "<table border=1><tr><td><b>sl no </b></td><td><b>Region</b></td><td><b>Location</b></td><td><b>Partner Name</b></td><td><b>Partner Code</b></td>";
                        strmailBody += "<tr><td>1 </td><td>" + Region + "</td><td> " + Location + " </td><td>" + PartnerName + " </td><td>" + PartnerCode + "  </td></tr></table>";
                        strmailBody += "<br/><br/>";
                        strmailBody += "</body></html>";
                        strmailBody += "Best Regards" + "<br/>" + "   IMS Team";
                        strmailBody += "<br/><br/>";
                        strmailBody += "Disclaimer: This is a system generated mail. Please do not reply to this mail. For any queries, Please log a call in https://serviceconnect.wipro.com <br/>";



                        string strMailSubject = "Partner Addition " + objUser.PartnerCode + "";
                        Helper.Sendmail(strMailFROM, ToMailIds, strMailSubject, strmailBody, CCMailIds, null, null);
                    }
```

Data layer code:

```
 public static DataTable GetPartnerMailDetails(UserMasterOL objUser)
 {
     if (objUser == null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("objUser");
     }

     DataTable dtGetPartnerMailDetails = new DataTable();
     dtGetPartnerMailDetails.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     try
     {

         DbCommand DbCmd = DataAccessbase.Database.GetStoredProcCommand(Constants.GetPartnerCreationMailDetails);
         DataAccessbase.Database.AddInParameter(DbCmd, "@PartnerCode", DbType.String, objUser.PartnerCode);
         dtGetPartnerMailDetails = DataAccessbase.Database.ExecuteDataSet(DbCmd).Tables[0];

     }
```

stored procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPartnerCreationMailDetails]
(

@PartnerCode   INT
)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

select rm.regionname,pm.PartnerCode,pm.partnername,lm.locationname from partnermaster pm 
           inner join regionmaster rm on
                             rm.regionid=pm.regionid 
           inner join locationmaster lm on
                             lm.locationid=pm.locationid

where pm.PartnerCode=@PartnerCode

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the TR on this line:

```
strmailBody += "<table border=1><tr><td><b>sl no </b></td><td><b>Region</b></td><td><b>Location</b></td><td><b>Partner Name</b></td><td><b>Partner Code</b></td>";
```

It should be

```
strmailBody += "<table border=1><tr><td><b>sl no </b></td><td><b>Region</b></td><td><b>Location</b></td><td><b>Partner Name</b></td><td><b>Partner Code</b></td></tr>";
```

Comment: I have changed. Again Values of location name,partnercode,region name are not displayed in mail.

Comment: Better debug and see what is happening.